# Currency Formatting With Dynamic Currency Symbol

Tags: c#, string, currency-formatting

In C# the code `Console.WriteLine("{0:c}", 998);` gives the output `$998` in default "US-Language" settings. But if I want to dynamically change my currency symbol to Pound, Sterling, Rupee or any currency symbol depending upon user preference, is there any way around to do this. Say, I call a method:

```
public void PrintInRightCurrencyFormat(decimal value, ICustomFormatter format)
{
     Console.WriteLine( ... ... ... );
}
```

And this method will print the value in required format.

One more thing is that is there any way to insert a custom currency symbol. My point is that if a currency comes with a new symbol(Like India did with its Rupee symbol), how to enable that immediately in code.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: You can do by `CultureInfo` but you need to take care for currency conversion; as $ 50 != Rs 50

Answer (score 4):

You could use a culture:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-GB"), "{0:c}", value));
```

or simply set the current thread culture to some user preference and then print the value:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
Console.WriteLine("{0:c}", value);
```

Comment: +1 Not only `could` you use a culture, you actually `should`! I would suggest to change culture at a more general level though, perhaps in the `web.config` or Thread level (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx). Also, note that currency should be stored as `decimal` and not `double` due to rounding differences.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you give a link which can give the predefined culture list.

Comment: @Arnab Das, here's one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.71).aspx